# convert method to generics

Tags: java

I have the following method signature, how do i convert it to be a template.

```
public static JSONContainer getMappedRootObject(JSONContainer clazz, String filename) {
    ...
    JSONContainer container = new Gson().fromJson(br, JSONContainer.class);
    return container;
}
```

This is what i came up with, is this right?

```
public static <T extends Object> T getMappedRootObject(Class<T> clazz, String filename) {
    T container = new Gson().fromJson(br, clazz);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: you could even remove the container variable: `return new Gson().fromJson(br, clazz);`

Comment: Except for the `extends Object` and the funky indentation, that looks right.

Comment: have you compiled and got any errors? because it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in your JSONContainer implementation, the "JSONContainer clazz" parameter is an instance of the target object, you may do the following:

```
public static <T> T getMappedRootObject(T instance, String filename) {
     //.......

    if (instance == null) {
        // handle this
    } else {
        T container = new Gson().fromJson(br, instance.getClass());
        return container;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `extends Object` is redundant.

Comment: Seeing as the instance isn't used in the original code, there's no reason not to use the Class object directly.

Comment: `if (T == null)`? I bet you need some water and sleep.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that the Type T will always have a certain kind of super class, you can [parametrize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) that ways
eg:. `<T extends JSONContainer>`

```
public static <T> T  getMappedRootObject(T clazz,String fileName){
    /**
     * ...
     * */
    T container = new Gson().fromJson(br, clazz.getClass());
    return container;
}
```